# What is a Farm Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Farm Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Farm Words™ | Not Farm Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ANIMAL | LIVESTOCK |
| ANIME | ANIMATION |
| BISON | OXEN |
| BUDGE | SHIFT |
| CHICKS | DUCKLINGS |
| FEND | EKE |
| FOILS | PARRIES |
| HAYLIFT | AIRLIFT |
| HICKS | REDNECKS |
| INWARDLY | EXTERNALLY |
| JIG | BARNDANCE |
| LIFTER | RAISER |
| LOIN | BRISKET |
| MEN | WOMEN |
| MIST | RAIN |
| MOVE | RELOCATE |
| NONSTICK | NONSKID |
| OILING | GREASING |
| PATENT | PENDING |
| PICKER | HARVESTER |
| PINES | EVERGREENS |
| RIOT | TURMOIL |
| RIPEST | JUICIEST |
| ROIST | CAROUSE |
| SHIRT | JEANS |
| SILOS | ELEVATORS |
| SPOIL | DECAY |
| SPRING | SUMMER |
| TICKS | FLEAS |
| TOIL | EFFORT |
| UNCOIL | UNWIND |
| UNLIVABLY | UNBEARABLY |
| WHIM | NOTION |
| WRING | TWIST |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Farm Words™,Not Farm Words™
ANIMAL,LIVESTOCK
ANIME,ANIMATION
BISON,OXEN
BUDGE,SHIFT
CHICKS,DUCKLINGS
FEND,EKE
FOILS,PARRIES
HAYLIFT,AIRLIFT
HICKS,REDNECKS
INWARDLY,EXTERNALLY
JIG,BARNDANCE
LIFTER,RAISER
LOIN,BRISKET
MEN,WOMEN
MIST,RAIN
MOVE,RELOCATE
NONSTICK,NONSKID
OILING,GREASING
PATENT,PENDING
PICKER,HARVESTER
PINES,EVERGREENS
RIOT,TURMOIL
RIPEST,JUICIEST
ROIST,CAROUSE
SHIRT,JEANS
SILOS,ELEVATORS
SPOIL,DECAY
SPRING,SUMMER
TICKS,FLEAS
TOIL,EFFORT
UNCOIL,UNWIND
UNLIVABLY,UNBEARABLY
WHIM,NOTION
WRING,TWIST
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Farm Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Farm Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Comment: It's really bugging me that the left side is all alphabetical but the right is not

Comment: It's tradition. Left side alphabetic, right side is a similar word.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Neither the Triad or the Cyclone ones were alphabetical.

Comment: Not everyone follows the same style.

Comment: @n_palum There's no requirement for them to be alphabetic, but in general a set of entries where order isn't important should be arranged in a recognizable way (alphabetically, by length, whatever) to show the ordering itself isn't part of the puzzle.  In any case, there is no special meaning to the order of the left entries, and the right entries are associated with the left by a (sometimes tenuous) semantic relationship, as is common with these puzzles. No need to read into it what isn't there; you could reorder one or both lists as you like without changing which list each word belongs in.

Comment: Got it now. I'll keep trying to figure out this relationship but no ideas so far.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be ask on these kind of word/phase puzzle - is "lion" a farm word?

Comment: @Alex It's the OP's discretion whether to answer questions about additional words; some will, some will after a while, and some won't.  I'm in a giving mood, so:  **yes**, LION is a Farm Word™.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess that:

> The farm words follow an "EIEIO" rule.  That is, if you take a farm word and replace each "E" with "IE" and each "I" with "O", you get another valid word.  For example: "LIFTER" -> "LOFTIER".
>  Most of the resulting words are common but I did have to double check that "anomal", "anomie", "onwardly", "nonstock", "pockier", "ropiest", and "sprong" were real words.

Comment: Nice catch. That should be it. +1

Comment: Very nicely done :)  The slightly more obscure replacement-words were needed to avoid a rather monotonous list of words all ending "er"; once you see the rule, verifying those last few would of course be easy, as you found. Great job!

Comment: I got as far as noticing the huge number of Is, and that the ones without Is have Es - was that observation plus "Farm" enough to get you to EIEIO? Or was there another realization in between?

Comment: @Personman I noticed near the bottom of the list that there were a bunch of words with "I" that could be changed to "O" (the bottom 11 words or so are all like that).  Then somehow I connected "farm" with "EIEIO", and thought of replacing "E" with "IE", and that worked for the words with "E" in them.  Lastly I had to check that all the weird words were actually real words.